# Ruby on Rails, uninitilized constant after renaming model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces

I'm very new to RoR.

I can use this source and calling "UsersFriends.test" with no problem.

```
class UsersFriends < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  module Status
    UNREAD = 0; READ = 1; GET = 2
  end

  def self.test
    Time.now.strftime('%F')
  end
end
```

Now I want to call it as "Friend" in console. So, I added "Friend::" in front of UsersFriends.
But I get "uninitilized constant Friend" when I use the following source.

```
class Friend::UsersFriends < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  module Status
    UNREAD = 0; READ = 1; GET = 2
  end

  def self.test
    Time.now.strftime('%F')
  end
end
```

Could you please explain me how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your class inside a directory called "friend"?

Comment: @jhonquintero class file is inside the "user" directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly do like this. If You want this kind of behaviour you should do few changes in app directory structure.

Create a Folder named friend and in that folder put the usersfriends.rb file.

```
app/models/friend/usersfriends.rb
```

(create a model named friend if necessary or else use user model and refer the same using user instead of friend)

Then, use

```
class Friend::UsersFriends < ActiveRecord::Base
```

You can find a good article of Model name spacing,  [here in this link](http://blog.makandra.com/2014/12/organizing-large-rails-projects-with-namespaces/)

Comment: I got it!! Thank you.

Comment: Np,  happy coding :-)